# Trying to share a directory, that is located in another hard drive connected to my computer, with a Windows 10 guest on QEMU/KVM

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 and Virtual Machine Manager 4.1.0.

When I try to add the directory that is located on another hard drive in Virtual Machine Manger, I get the following error: "Error starting domain: operation failed: Unable to find a satisfying virtiofsd".

How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: I got this to work by installing virtiofsd in Ubuntu (host): sudo apt install virtiofsd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work by installing virtiofsd in Ubuntu (host): sudo apt install virtiofsd.

On Windows (guest), I installed:

- WinFsp 2023: https://github.com/winfsp/winfsp/releases/
- virtio-win-guest-tools.exe : https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/archive-virtio/virtio-win-0.1.240-1/

Then I went to the Windows' Start menu and typed 'services'. After the Services app loaded, I found "VirtIO-FS Service", double-clicked it, set the Startup Type to Automatic, and started the service.

[image: VirtIO-FS Service]